# What is the default value of Validity in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, validation

In angular project, once I set the `$setValidity` as `false`

```
$scope.form[key].$setValidity("has_already_taken", false);
```

How can I set Validity True?

I tried  `$scope.form[key].$setValidity(null , true);`
But it's never working.
I am new to angular and any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you set `has_already_taken`'s validity as `false` so you have to `has_already_taken`'s validity as `true`.

Please see reference [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setValidity)